# ASP.NET 301 Redirects

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an old domain, say *http://siteA.com*, I moved to *http://siteB.com*, I want to redirect all requests like *http://siteA.com/myPage.aspx?param=text* to *http://siteB.com/myPage.aspx?param=text*

Is it possible to do that with a shared hosting account running IIS 6 and ASP.net 4?

Comment: Who is your hosting provider?